# Regex to ignore splitting on a character if inside parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string on "," only if it is after closed parenthesis, but ignore if there is ")," with in parenthesis.

```
 String criteria = name:(eq:j,ohn),id:(eq:123)
```

I am able sucessfully split above string using regex:

```
 criteria.split("(?<=[)])(?=[,])(\\,)");
```

Index 0 : name:(eq:j,ohn)

Index 1: id:(eq:123)

But, if i have :

```
 String criteria = name:(eq:jo),hn),id:(eq:123)
```

The above regex doesn't work as I expect.

**actual result:**

index 0: name:(eq:jo)

index 1: hn)

index 2: id:(eq:123)

**expected result:**

index 0: name:(eq:jo),hn)

index 1: id:(eq:123)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Try `.split("(?<=\\))(?=,(?![^()]*\\)))")`

Comment: Thanks wiktor, it works for above scenario. but if i try String criteria = "id:(eq:123),name:(eq:jo),hn(pa))"; it doesnt work.

Comment: Please explain why down vote, i will learn and make sure i wont repeat again.

Comment: `(eq:123),name:(eq:jo),hn(pa))` Even though this is not nested parenthesis, does it matter if it is nested ?

Comment: @Sln The logic i am looking for is , "split on comma followed by closing parenthesis , ignore and dont split on comma if comma appears in parenthesis"

Comment: @Jon Sampson thanks for formatting my question and sorry to cause you extra work. I will get better at this.

Comment: The problem is that both `),` look exactly the same. How would you decide if a `),` is a closing one or not?

Comment: in my example string : name:(eq:jo),hn), after jo is enclosed withing parenthesis that starts befor